# Directional derivative of x and y as functions of t

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, parametrization

Consider the function $\frac{1}{1+x^2+3y^2}$ and the trajectory x(t) = t, y(t) = t(t-2)

I am asked to show that the directional vector in the direction of motion is given by $-\frac{2t(6t^2 - 18t + 13)}{\sqrt{1 + 4(t-1)^2}(1+t^2+3t^2(t-2)^2)^2)}$

I started by finding ∇f(x,y) = $(\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2+3y^2)^2}, \frac{-6y}{(1+x^2+3y^2)^2})$

Now using the definition of directional vector which is ∇f(x,y).$\hat{u}$ I constructed the $\hat{u}$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2 + t^2(t-2)^2)}}(t, t(t-2))$

Finally I calculated the dot product and tried to simplify. However, I couldn't reach the expression I am asked to show. I don't know if I made a calculation error or my approach is incorrect. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to calculate the dot product of $\nabla f$ and the *velocity* of the trajectory.

Comment: Why is that? @KurtG.

Comment: Because the velocity of the trajectory $(x(t),y(t))$ is tangent to the curve. Take as curve a circle around the origin to convince yourself of this.

Comment: The velocity vector is the speed and *direction of motion*.  The point $(x(t),y(t))$ is a position vector at time $t$.